# make my jhipster application work with an existing keycloak

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak, jhipster

I have a problem with jhispter when I want to integrate it to an existing keycloak application. using the jhispter application with the docker image provided for keycloak, it works normally but when I point to another keycloak application, it produces the following error and I don't know why this error occurs:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/EL/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-spring-web/3.0.0/springfox-spring-web-3.0.0.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/web/plugins/DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webFluxRequestHandlerProvider' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/EL/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-spring-webflux/3.0.0/springfox-spring-webflux-3.0.0.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/web/plugins/WebFluxRequestHandlerProvider.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.reactive.WebFluxAutoConfiguration$EnableWebFluxConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setConfigurers' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.reactive.ReactiveOAuth2ClientImportSelector$OAuth2ClientWebFluxSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setClientRegistrationRepository' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientRegistrationRepository' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/client/reactive/ReactiveOAuth2ClientConfigurations$ReactiveClientRegistrationRepositoryConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.InMemoryReactiveClientRegistrationRepository]: Factory method 'clientRegistrationRepository' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to resolve Configuration with the provided Issuer of "http://localhost:9080/auth/realms/newKeycloak"

Thank you in advance for any help!!

spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.oidc.issuer-uri= http://localhost:9080/auth/realms/myrealm

spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.oidc.client-id= web_app

spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.oidc.client-secret=mysercrtekey

spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.oidc.scope=openid,profile,email

Comment: Probably something wrong in your application*.yml

Comment: here is how the file is configured:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          oidc:
            issuer-uri: http://localhost:9080/auth/realms/myrealm
        registration:
          oidc:
            client-id: web_app
            client-secret: <client-id>
            scope: openid,profile,email

Comment: Please edit your question rather than putting YAML in comments (it's unreadable). In your error it's newKeycloak not myrealm

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem may be the version of keycloak that is not compatible. when i try with version 12 and 14 of keycloak everything works without issues. but as soon as i put the version 15, nothing works anymore